# Load resource file from app inside a library in android

Tags: android

Is there a way that i can see the resources from my app within my library?

I tried

`Class res = Class.forName( extras.getString( R.string.getClass() ) ); <- apps' R class

final Field[] fields = res.getFields(); <- returns nothing

for(final Field field:fields){

....

}`

Thanks

**Update** 
The app could see the whole list by just getting R of the library, but now i cant get string value from the app

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you really want to be using a raw resource, rather than the strings resource?  If you want random access to strings, reading a file into memory would make things much easier.

The nature of the strings resource is more of a compile-time linking, not a database to search at run-time.